# Type of nonlinear 1D Heat Equation with Neumann bounary conditions, functional co-efficients and boundaries

Tags: differential-equations

I've a follow on question from [How to solve 1D heat equation with Neumann boundary conditions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138954/how-to-solve-1d-heat-equation-with-neumann-boundary-conditions)

The equation I have is more complicated with additional terms.

$$aF(u)\frac {\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-bH(u)\frac {\partial u}{\partial t} = 0$$

with

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=0} =\frac{c*(u(x=0,t)-20)}{H(u(x=0,t) )}  \quad (1)$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg|_{x=h} =\frac{-e*(u(x=h,t)-10)}{H(u(x=h,t))} \quad (2)$$

$$u(x,0)=20  \quad (3)$$

The terms $F$ and $H$ are functions of $u$. The terms $a, b, c, e$ are constant coefficients.  Since I have introduced extra terms, I suppose this PDE is no longer classified as the heat/wave equation?
Could this be called a nonlinear form of the heat/wave type of PDE?
I have functional coefficients of $u$ and the boundary conditions also includes a function of $u$. Is it possible to solve this equation?

```
Tamb = 20

Tbase = 20

Hbase = 10

Hsurface = 10

SP = 0.005

CyDe = 11.4

vdge = 0.8
```

Here are functional coefficients.

```
F[u_] := 4E - 10*u^3 - 7 E - 07*u^2 + 4 E - 04*u + 
  2.4 E - 01

G[u_] := -2.6 E - 08*u^2 + 9.1 E - 05*u + 1.6 E - 03;

H[u_] := 3.8*G[u] + 1 E - 10*u^3;
```

Solution A does NOT work, is `NDSolve` useful for this PDE?

```
solA = NDSolve[{CyDe*vdge*F[u[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + 
          SP*3600*H[u[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
         0, (D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 
         Hsurface*(u[t, 0] - Tamb)/H[u[t, 0]], (D[u[t, x], x] /. 
           x -> 1) == -Hbase*(u[t, 1] - Tbase)/H[u[t, 1]], 
        u[0, x] == 20 }, u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}];
```

Solution B does not work either? What is the difference between Solution B (`NDSolveValue`) with solution A (`NDSolve`)?

```
solB = NDSolveValue[{CyDe*vdge*F[u[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], {t, 1}] + 
         SP*3600*H[u[t, x]]*D[u[t, x], {x, 2}] == 
        NeumannValue[Hsurface*(u[t, 0] - Tamb)/H[u[t, 0]], x == 0] - 
         NeumannValue[-Hbase*(u[t, 1] - Tbase)/H[u[t, 1]], x == 1], u[0, x] == 20}, 
      u, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, 
      Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
        "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]; Plot3D[
     solB[t, x], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]

    Plot[solB[10, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The error message includes:

`NDSolveValue::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve.`

Comment: 1. Where's the definition of `Tamb`? 2. `(D[u[t, x], x] /. 
           x -> 0) == -Hbase*(u[t, 1] - Tbase)/H[u[t, 1]]` is different from the b.c. in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: The Tamb = 20 is just a constant, equivalent to a, b etc. It was just easier to write out in latex as general constants.

Comment: I mean, something is wrong with the b.c. `(D[u[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == -Hbase*(u[t, 1] - Tbase)/H[u[t, 1]]`, please compare it to the one in $\LaTeX$ carefully.

Comment: I've changed to x -> 1, I believe that corrects the error.  Thanks.

Comment: When I run your solA, I get u = 20 everywhere. If you plug in u[t,x]=20, that satisfies the pde, and all bc and ic.  Strange

Comment: Thanks Bill, I've been alerted to some errors with the formulation. I've corrected the LATEX eqns here: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17821/1d-heat-equation-for-conduction-with-convective-bounary-conditions

Comment: Please also update your $\LaTeX$ and the code here .